# HPLIP will not open

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp, hplip

I have just installed HPLIP using the Ubuntu Software Centre in to 12.04LTS.   The icon has appeared in Unity, but nothing happens when I click on it.   I have run hp-check -t in terminal and get the following output:

```
nigel@nigel-F3Se:~$ hp-check -t
error: Unable to locate models.dat file

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 0.0.0)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 14.3

Copyright (c) 2011-14 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the
HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies
are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.                                    
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro    
supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball   
has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.                      
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode    
will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).   

Saving output in log file: hp-check.log

Initializing. Please wait...
|Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hp-check", line 206, in <module>
    core.init()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 412, in init
    self.distro_name = self.distros_index[self.distro]
KeyError: 0
```

I have HPLIP installed on two other computers using 12.04LTS without this problem.   Any ideas or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: try typing `hp-setup` in a terminal command

Comment: and if that fails try `sudo hp-setup`

Comment: Thank you for the help - sorry not to answer more quickly.  Have tried both suggestions with results below.  Printer is on a wireless network, but hp-setup is looking for usb.   Any other suggestions most gratefully received.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the terminal output:nigel@nigel-F3Se:~$ hp-setup
error: Unable to locate models.dat file

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 0.0.0)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0


Using connection type: usb

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you've already solved your problem with this printer by going (as I always do) **direct** to HPLIP and downloading the most up to date version - **3.14.1** - and installing from your terminal. Software Centre I avoid as it's never up to date, HP-wise. 
I've downloaded direct from HPLIP on numerous occasions without any trouble. Just make sure your wireless printer/fax is switched on when you start the whole process and during the process of installation un-install any version you already have. 
The automatic installer is very good.
Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the error occurs when you try to upgrade to the 3.14.1

I had the same problem, install the required dependency packages that are on [the HP page](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/manual/distros/ubuntu.html).